# Не выполняется запрос командой execute

Tags: php

Имеется такой код:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array())
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    if(!empty($params))
    {
        foreach($params as $key =>$val)
        {
            $stmt->bindValue(":", $key, $val);
        }
    }
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}
```

при попытке его выполнить выходит сообщение "***Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in "путь к файлу" on line 30***" здесь указывается как раз на строчку `$stmt->execute();`. В результате выводится пустой массив. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы не передали параметры для запроса. Параметр - это первый аргумент `bindValue`, а не второй. То есть

```
$stmt->bindValue(":" . $key, $val);
```

Ну и цикл здесь не нужен вовсе, `execute` сам умеет принимать массив параметров.

```
public function query($sql, $params = array())
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt;
}
```